# go template: how to pass the variable returned from a function to next command in pipeline

Tags: go, go-templates

I have this function.

```
func OrderedParamsFromUri(uri string) []string {
    matches := pathParamRE.FindAllStringSubmatch(uri, -1)
    result := make([]string, len(matches))
    for i, m := range matches {
        result[i] = m[1]
    }
    return result
}
```

I want to use this function inside my template to check if the returned `result` contains items or not. 
I know I can do something like this:

```
  ( .OperationId | OrderedParamsFromUri | //here i want to check for the empty slice)
  .OperationId  =>  this is the argument.
```

I know I can check if the returned slice is empty or not using `if not .returnedSlice`
But how to combine these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
{{ if not (.OperationId | OrderedParamsFromUri) }}
    empty
{{ else }}
    {{ (.OperationId | OrderedParamsFromUri) }}
{{ end }}
```

Or

```
{{ if not (OrderedParamsFromUri .OperationId) }}
    empty
{{ else }}
    {{ (OrderedParamsFromUri .OperationId) }}
{{ end }}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/rkt7wP_vS4n